# Naming Convention for Uninitialized Constants Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I name my constants which are `static final` like ALL_UPPER_CASE

However, sometimes you need to use a field as a constant but cannot define it as `final` because it needs to be initialized later.

For example:

```
public class ExampleClass {
     public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
     public static int constantValue;

     public ExampleClass() {
          // ...
     }

     private static void init(boolean condition) {
          if (condition) {
             constantValue = 42;
          } else {
             constantValue = 1;
          }
     }
}
```

Question: is there any kind of naming convention for these? How would you do it or go about it?

I just like to know stuff; that's all!

Comment: And this dynamic variable is also `public`?

Comment: @KevinWallis it may be initialized in its class or outside

Comment: The value of this static constant is to be initialized by a non-static function?

Comment: @FredK yes? does this change things?

Comment: @rz3r0 I think it is a very bad design when such a `static` variable is set outside and it has nothing to do with oop :D

Comment: Then it is not a constant. If one instance of ExampleClass has `condition` equal to true, and another instance has `condition` equal to false, what should happen?

Comment: @FredK oh right. I edited my question

Comment: It is still not a constant - `init` can be called any number of times, with different values of its argument.

Comment: Naming conventions are established on conventional cliché which is not the case of your example so maybe there's no stuff for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `constantValue` is not a constant. It is merely a static field which does not change after it has been initialized. I would stick with the Sun naming conventions and keep the name camelCase.
However, in the case you've given, if I absolutely wanted to show that this is a constant I would create an enum :

```
public enum ExampleEnum {

    TRUE_CONDITION(42), FALSE_CONDITION(1);

    private final int value;

    private ExampleEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then ExampleClass would become :

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
    private static ExampleEnum myEnum;

    private static void init(boolean condition) {
        if (condition) {
            myEnum = ExampleEnum.TRUE_CONDITION;
        } else {
            myEnum = ExampleEnum.FALSE_CONDITION;
        }
    }

    public static int getConstantValue() {
        return myEnum.getValue();
    }

}
```

This way, you get the feeling you're working with constants, and you're not breaking encapsulation.

Comment: maybe the `if(condition)` code can be moved to an own method from the enum?

Comment: Arthur's example is a better way to write the rz3r0's example but I think the sentence "if I absolutely wanted to show that this is a constant" it's not correct. In this solution what I see is that the variable `condition` can assume well determined values (by the enum) but it's a variable not a constant.

Comment: True enough. I should rephrase the sentence like so: if I absolutely wanted to show that the value could take very specific values..."